# Obtain the main memory layout, not specific to only a single riscv implementation

Tags: riscv

I am working on a operating systems kernel for the riscv isa, mostly using assembly language. I like to use the riscv specification and the SiFive FU540 specification as reference.

I need to make the kernel know which address ranges are not reserved for other components and therefore are available for the kernel and its processes. This has to happen in a way, applicable to as many future riscv implementations as possible. However, I could only find the memory map specific to the SiFive FU540 implementation.

In the [privileged architecture version 1.10 riscv specification chapter 8](https://riscv.org/wp-content/plugins/pdf-viewer/stable/web/viewer.html?file=https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf#page=87&zoom=auto,-18,688), it says that there is a device tree to communicate platform information to the kernel, but I could not find enough information about how it functions.

> To reduce porting effort for OS boots, we have reverted back to using Device Trees to communicateplatform  information  to  the  kernel,  so  this  chapter  is  out  of  date.  Cong  string  was  designedfor other uses in addition, but for now, we are staying with a standard device tree model.

Now my questions:

1. Is there a document that talks about the device tree of the riscv ISA in depth?
2. Is the device tree model a temporary solution, so that I should just wait until it gets replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devices tree is mainly Linux kernel concept. Then for Risc-V device tree documentation you should look at [kernel documentation here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/riscv/cpus.txt?h=v4.20-rc5) in my opinion.
All the code belong to Risc-V can be found on [arch/riscv/ directory](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/riscv?h=v4.20-rc5).

Answer (score 0):

The device tree standard itself is a bit odd: [devicetree.org](https://devicetree.org) maintains a [device tree standard](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/tag/v0.2), but that's more focused on binary encodings and such as opposed to what the nodes actually mean.

The definition of a device tree node is specific to a particular compatible string and the best documentation for these lives next to the Linux source code, in [Documentation/devicetree/bindings](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings).  Your best bet is to just grep for a compatible string in there.  The documentation is pretty decent, but we of course would be happy to hear any issues you have -- or ever better, patches :).

The device tree bindings in the Linux repository are meant to be generic (ie, not specific to Linux) but since they're in the same repository as the Linux source code they tend to have some Linux-isms sneak in.  In RISC-V land we're attempting to keep our device tree entries compatible between all operating systems, but that's an ongoing chunk of work.  I know our Zephyr port also uses device tree and while it's mostly compatible with the Linux device trees there's some differences.

We plan on using device tree for the foreseeable future as part of the RISC-V Linux port.  Our intent is that device trees will be treated as a stable ABI just like all our others.  In other words: once a binding is in the Linux source tree we won't change it in a binary-incompatible way.  How well this plans out remains to be seen.